# Constant time Haskell List (Time Complexity? Haskell data types?) - Homework related

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, time-complexity

I'm currently taking a CS class in Haskell and I'm having some serious problem understanding some materials.

For one of my assignments, I'm given 2 data types and I'm asked to write a append function that has constant time append.

I'm given:

```
data NNList a = Sing a | Append ( NNList a) ( NNList a) deriving (Eq)
data CList a = Nil | NotNil ( NNList a) deriving (Eq)
```

and I'm asked to write a function:

```
CListAppend :: CList a -> CList a -> CList a
```

I'm not sure what I missed in my CS education but I often find myself confused with time and space complexity, how would I actually know if a function is `constant time`? And can anyone provide me on some idea of how to proceed with this question?

My attempt:

```
CListAppend :: CList a -> CList a -> CList a
CListAppend Nil rl = rl
CListAppend ll Nil = ll
CListAppend ll rl = NotNil $ Append ll rl
```

This reports and error of returning NNList instead of CList. Is there anyway to convert that?

Comment: You don't want the work performed in your function to vary significantly in the size of the inputs. In your case, you probably don't want to be using recursion in a constant-time solution.

Comment: Hint: You have to return a `CList`. What are the constructors of `CList`?

Comment: @hammar, how do I actually `construct` something in Haskell? It's certainly not `CList $ Append ll rl` or anything like that..

Comment: @user1043625: The data constructors are on the right hand side of the `=` in `data CList a = ...`, so in this case they are `Nil` and `NotNil`.

Comment: Doing something in constant time means that the operation is independent of the size of its input (the function always takes the same amount of time, i.e., constant). W.r.t. this your attempt looks promising, except for the type error of course. As others have pointed out: what are the available constructors of `CList`? You have to use one of them to obtain a `CList`.

Comment: @chris, Ok, thanks for the info. so doing NotNil $ .... would convert ... to a CList but how do I make ll & rl the correct data type for Append?

Comment: Are you aware of "pattern-matching"? (You already applied it in some of your equations to make sure that one of the arguments to your function is `Nil`.)

Comment: @chris, yeah. I'm aware of pattern matching. The first two cases would cover if ll / rl is Nil, since it passes those two first cases, doesn't it mean that ll and rl isn't Nil and thus it is NotNil. Since it is NotNil, isn't it automatically a NNList?

Comment: Well you as a human know that `ll` and `rl` have to be of the form `NotNil ...`, but since the type of `NotNil x` is `CList a`, you have to explicitly extract the argument to obtain something of type `NNList a`.

Comment: Ah! now I remember. `CListAppend ll@(NotNil nll) rl@(NotNil nrl) = NonNil $ Append nll nrl`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Time complexity is a way to describe how many *steps* are required to compute the answer relative to the *size* of the input. What constitutes a *step* and how you calculate *size* depends on the problem.

For instance, if you have an unsorted pile of business cards, searching for a particular one will require a number of steps proportional to the number of cards. If you double the size of your pile, the average number of cards you have to examine will also double.

On the other hand, if you pre-sorted the cards, you could play the "high-low" game to cut the size of the pile in half each time you look at a card. Doubling the size of the pile now only requires *one* extra step when looking for a particular card.

Those are examples of linear and logarithmic time complexities, respectively. In your case, you want constant time complexity. That means no matter how large the two lists are, appending them takes the *same number of steps*.

You can usually get an idea by walking through the algorithm on paper with different inputs, but there are more precise methods. Here's an example of an *append* function using the standard `[]` list implementation:

```
append []     bs = bs
append (a:as) bs = a : append as bs
```

We'll count a recursive call to *append* as one step; alternatively we could count number of invocations of `(:)`. When the first argument is an empty list, `[]`, there are no recursive calls. When the list contains a single element, `[1]`, we evaluate `1 : append [] bs`, so we have one recursive call. Now double the input size with `[1,2]` and count the recursive calls. Then double again with `[1,2,3,4]`, etc. You can then roughly estimate if the number of steps is constant, linear, logarithmic, exponential, etc in the size of the input.

Answer (score 0):

The last definition is wrong. 
If `ll` is `NotNil x` and `rl` is `NotNil y` then your definition should be

```
CListAppend (NotNil x) (NotNil y) = NotNil ( Append x y )
```

You are however applying Append on values of type `CList a`.

Also this solution is constant time. The Append constructor does no processing. Also pattern matching happens in constant time.